# Box2d jetski on water

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, physics

At the moment I am trying to code a 2d game where a jetski is riding on water. If you press on the screen the jetski should dive down and jump back up on release. How do I have to do this in Box2d? My idea was to put a rectangular body as the water and an other one as the jetski. Since I am new to box2d I don't really know how I should bring this into code.
I hope one of you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fCT-EjlF9I) that you want? If it, creating buoyancy, then applying a downwards force when you want the jetski to go down. The tutorial in the window, along with [this page](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/02/21/using-box2d-buoyancy-controller-to-create-a-pool/) and [this page](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy), should hopefully help you get started.

Now, this might not work for you project, but the general idea is still solid. A really simple version could function like this:

- Your characters is positioned at some pointed on the y-axis, the surface of the water.
- When the screen is pressed, but the character downwards.
- If the screen isn't pressed and the character is under water, move it upward.

To improve on this design you could have the character rise until it hits a point slightly above the surface, then let it fall down again, to simulate the upwards force making the character jump out of the water.

I don't know how your game is supposed to work, so you'll probably have to find your own system, but I hope some of this can be of help to you.